# Replacing of XML Namespaces via VBA doesn't work after adding new data

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I'm generating a XML file from an Excel table with a VBA code. The code also replaces namespaces that Excel names incorrectly. It works, as long as I only have a single set of data for an element (the element can occur more than once). As soon as I want to add new data, the VBA code only creates and saves the file without changing the namespaces. Can someone tell me how to change the code so it still changes the namespaces after adding new elements?

The VBA code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportXml()
    Dim exportResult As XlXmlExportResult
    Dim exportPath As String
    Dim xmlMap As String
    Dim fileContents As String
    exportPath = RequestExportPath()
    If exportPath = "" Or exportPath = "False" Then Exit Sub
    xmlMap = range("XmlMap")
    exportResult = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(xmlMap).Export(exportPath, True)
    If exportResult = xlXmlExportValidationFailed Then
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
    fileContents = ReadInTextFile(exportPath)
    fileContents = ApplyReplaceRules(fileContents)
    WriteTextToFile exportPath, fileContents
End Sub

Function ApplyReplaceRules(fileContents As String) As String
    Dim replaceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim findWhatRange As range
    Dim replaceWithRange As range
    Dim findWhat As String
    Dim replaceWith As String
    Dim cell As Integer
    Set findWhatRange = range("FindWhat")
    Set replaceWithRange = range("ReplaceWith")
    For cell = 1 To findWhatRange.Cells.Count
        findWhat = findWhatRange.Cells(cell)
        If findWhat > "" Then
            replaceWith = replaceWithRange.Cells(cell)
            fileContents = Replace(fileContents, findWhat, replaceWith)
        End If
    Next cell
    ApplyReplaceRules = fileContents
End Function

Function RequestExportPath() As String
    Dim messageBoxResult As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim exportPath As String
    Dim message As String
    message = "The file already exists. Do you want to replace it?"
    Do While True
        exportPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "XML Files (*.xml),*.xml")
        If exportPath = "False" Then Exit Do
        If Not FileExists(exportPath) Then Exit Do
        messageBoxResult = MsgBox(message, vbYesNo, "File Exists")
        If messageBoxResult = vbYes Then Exit Do
    Loop
    RequestExportPath = exportPath
End Function

Function FileExists(path As String) As Boolean
    Dim fileSystemObject
    Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileExists = fileSystemObject.FileExists(path)
End Function

Function ReadInTextFile(path As String) As String
    Dim fileSystemObject
    Dim textStream
    Dim fileContents As String
    Dim line As String
    Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set textStream = fileSystemObject.OpenTextFile(path)
    fileContents = textStream.ReadAll
    textStream.Close
    ReadInTextFile = fileContents
End Function

Sub WriteTextToFile(path As String, fileContents As String)
    Dim fileSystemObject
    Dim textStream
    Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set textStream = fileSystemObject.CreateTextFile(path, True)
    textStream.Write fileContents
    textStream.Close
End Sub
```

I named everything I wanted to change `FindWhat` and everything that should replace it `ReplaceWith`.

I expect the output to be e.g. `Melder`, instead it still shows me `ns1:Melder`. This only happens, when I have more than one listing of an element. Otherwise it works.

A sampel of the XML I get right now is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:LIEFERUNG-DIREK xmlns:ns1="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/direk/2015-01-01" xmlns:ns2="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1" erstellzeit="2001-12-17T09:30:47Z" stufe="Test" dateireferenz="1" bereich="Statistik">
        <ns1:MELDER>
            <ns1:FIRMENNR>Muster</ns1:FIRMENNR>
            <ns1:NAME>Muster</ns1:NAME>
        </ns1:MELDER>   
        <ns1:FORMULAR-K3>
               <ns1:K3 lfdnr="1" meldeart="endgueltig">
                 <ns1:BILANZ>
                    <ns1:BILANZSTICHTAG>2015-12-31</ns1:BILANZSTICHTAG>
                 </ns1:BILANZ>
               </ns1:K3>
               <ns1:K3 lfdnr="2" meldeart="endgueltig">
                 <ns1:BILANZ>
                    <ns1:BILANZSTICHTAG>2015-12-31</ns1:BILANZSTICHTAG>
                 </ns1:BILANZ>
               </ns1:K3>
        </ns1:FORMULAR-K3>
</ns1:LIEFERUNG-DIREK>
```

What I need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LIEFERUNG-DIREK xmlns:bbk="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/direk/2015-01-01" version="1.0" erstellzeit="2019-06-07T08:30:54Z" stufe="Test" dateireferenz="1" bereich="Statistik" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/direk/2015-01-01 BbkXmwDirek_2015.xsd">
        <bbk:MELDER>
            <FIRMENNR>Muster</FIRMENNR>
            <bbk:NAME>Muster</bbk:NAME>
        </bbk:MELDER>   
        <FORMULAR-K3>
            <K3 lfdnr="1" meldeart="endgueltig">
                <BILANZ>
                    <BILANZSTICHTAG>2015-12-31</BILANZSTICHTAG>
                </BILANZ>
            </K3>
            <K3 lfdnr="2" meldeart="endgueltig">
                <BILANZ>
                    <BILANZSTICHTAG>2015-12-31</BILANZSTICHTAG>
                </BILANZ>
            </K3>
        </FORMULAR-K3>
</LIEFERUNG-DIREK>
```

As you can see `K3` appears more than once. If it only appears once, the code works.

Comment: Interesting question but without data we cannot help. Please post a small data and/or XML sample so your code is runnable from an empty Excel workbook (i.e., [MCVE]). Also, please post desired result.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections! I will post a small sample, I hope its okay.

Comment: Thank you for update but it appears you are running through unknown ranges on a spreadsheet. Where is the data to render your desired result? What is in `range("FindWhat")` or `range("ReplaceWith")`? Show how you are calling functions. We need runnable code to reproduce issue(s) from our empty workbooks.

Comment: `findWhat` contains the namespaces I want to change: `ns1:MELDER`, `ns1:FIRMENNR`,  `ns1:NAME`,  `ns1:FORMULAR-K3`,  `ns1:K3`, `ns1:BILANZ`,  `ns1:LIEFERUNG-DIREK`, `ns1:BILANZSTICHTAG`

Comment: `ReplacWith` contains the replacing namespaces : `bbk:MELDER`, `FIRMENNR`,  `bbk:NAME`,  `FORMULAR-K3`,  `K3`, `BILANZ`,  `LIEFERUNG-DIREK`, `BILANZSTICHTAG`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than handle XML changes using text files read/writes, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML. VBA can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with the MSXML library. One of XSLT's strengths is handling namespaces including default and multiple prefixes which is a challenge with your needs.

Specifically, below XSLT walks down the tree re-writing the needed elements for their local names (i.e., without prefixes) mapping to the new default: `xmlns="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/direk/2015-01-01"`.

**XSLT** *(save below as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/direk/2015-01-01"
                              xmlns:bbk="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/direk/2015-01-01 BbkXmwDirek_2015.xsd"
                              xmlns:ext="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="ext" >
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="bbk_nmsp" select="'http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vbbk">
       <xsl:element name="bbk:x" namespace="{$bbk_nmsp}"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:LIEFERUNG-DIREK">
        <xsl:element name="LIEFERUNG-DIRE" namespace="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/direk/2015-01-01">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[.='xsi']"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ext:node-set($vbbk)/*/namespace::*[.=$bbk_nmsp]"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/direk/2015-01-01 BbkXmwDirek_2015.xsd</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:MELDER">
        <xsl:element name="bbk:MELDER">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:FIRMENNR|doc:NAME|doc:FORMULAR-K3|doc:K3|doc:BILANZ|doc:BILANZSTICHTAG">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/direk/2015-01-01">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWF/1)

**VBA**

```vb
Sub XSLTransform()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\InputXML.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False    
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT_Script.xml"        

    ' TRANSFORM XML 
    xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\OutputXML.xml"

    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Excuse my late answer and thank you very much for your help! I already thought about an XSL Stylesheet but did not know how to use with the mutliple prefixes, so thats great. Unfortunately, excel does not load the XSL file. Instead the error message appears that the namespace `xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"` does not contain functions.

Comment: See update to XSLT script with `xmlns:ext` assignment. MSXML has its own extended library.